# SQL find the oldest date from a range of dates where attributes repeat from month to month

Tags: sql, sql-server

Need help isolating the oldest date from a table where the following attributes:[process id],[tracking id],[bp] are identical in the previous months.

I run a recon report once a month. Need to identify if records in this month Recon Report appeared in previous months. If the record appeard in a previous report than I need to identify the oldest date an *Issue* has been opened, so I can identify delinquents.  The last time the report ran was 6/31/2020, but the issue has been open for the last three months.

[image]

Here are the results that I would I like to see.

[image]

Below is they query that I am running.

```
declare @date  datetime
set @date= '6/30/2020'
select
    DATEDIFF(d,date, @date) as [Number of days outstanding],
    [Business Profile Name], 
    [Unit], 
    [Tracking ID], 
    [Owner], 
    [Issue]
from 
    [Recon_Report] 
where 
    concat ([process id],[tracking id],[bp]) in 
    (
        select 
            (concat ([process id],[tracking id],[bp]))
        from 
            [Recon_Report] 
        where 
            date = @date
    )
and date < @date
order by  [process id],[tracking id],[bp], Date asc
```

I tried adding this to query:

```
min(DATEDIFF(d,date, @date))
```

But I get an error mesage:

*Msg 8120, Level 16, State 1, Line 19
Column 'Recon_Report.Date' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a solution that worked for me.

```
 declare @date  datetime
    set @date= '6/30/2020'
    select
        DATEDIFF(d,min(date), @date) as [Number of days outstanding],
        [Business Profile Name], 
        [Unit], 
        [Tracking ID], 
        [Owner], 
        [Issue]
    from 
        [Recon_Report] 
    where 
        concat ([process id],[tracking id],[bp]) in 
        (
            select 
                (concat ([process id],[tracking id],[bp]))
            from 
                [Recon_Report] 
            where 
                date = @date
        )
    and date < @date
    group by 
        [Business Profile Name], 
        [Unit], 
        [Tracking ID], 
        [Owner], 
        [Issue]
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use window functions.  I think you want:

```
select DATEDIFF(d,date, @date) as [Number of days outstanding],
       rr.*
from (select rr.*,
             max(case when date = @date then 1 else 0 end) over (partition by [process id], [tracking id], [bp]) as on_date,
             dense_rank() over (partition by [process id], [tracking id], [bp] order by date) as seqnum
      from Recon_Report rr
      where date <= @date
     ) rr
where seqnum = 1
order by  [process id], [tracking id], [bp], Date asc
```

Comment: Using a windows function is the way to go. It's awfully bold to down-vote someone w 1M reputation instead of asking a follow up question.

Comment: Your query *Issue*'s that were closed out prior to 6/30/2020 report. I do not understand why.

In other words, I am seeing records that was an *Issue* on 3/31/2020 and did not appear in the 6/30/2020 Recon Report. I dont understand why.

Comment: @user716255 . . . This only includes the *oldest* record for each set of records in the `partition by`.  That appears to be what the question is asking for:  "Need to identify the oldest date an Issue has been opened".